# Domain stuck in google DNS?

Tags: dns, gmail, smtp

I have a customer who made a mess of things setting up google apps. She has now closed her google apps account and we are getting emails via POP to gmail successfully using gmail fetch.

However in gmail when trying to add her domain email address hello@domain.com as a FROM, after adding the SMTP mail server mail.domain.com, the verify email bounces with the error

```
Technical details of temporary failure:
DNS Error: Address resolution of mail.domain.com.domain.com.
```

It looks to me like the domain might still be somewhere in google DNS and pre-pending the mailserver to it...

Or something like that. Any ideas anyone?

[UPDATE]  I just realised, that even if I used a different mail server when adding the addition email address the error is the same.   i.e. if I add as the SMTP server `mail.mymailserver.com` then the bounce still says `DNS Error: Address resolution of mail.domain.com.domain.com.`

I have no idea where it is getting that from.

Comment: I am not sure I follow: Have you tried *dig example.com any* on a linux computer to see the status of things?

Comment: WHen adding a new email address in gmail you have to use an external SMTP server to send through, not gmail's servers.  When you are setting it up it asks for the SMTP server name, user name and password and then checks the credentials before sending a verification email.  That verification email is what is bouncing with the odd address it is trying to use.  Check an update I am about to add

Comment: You got me on this one brother!! It sounds like a code error. Is the big G suffering from m1cr0$0f7itis??

Comment: It actually gets curiouser and curiouser.  External emails are getting to the address OK, but if I send from her own gmail account to that same address...well, so far it hasn't arrived, I reckon that like the others it will be delayed until it dies.  But if I send from my gmail account to her email address it does arrive.   Is it even possible to get tech support from google?

Comment: Yeah! They have a gmail address... okay that wasn't funny. (Well- a little.) I know that Google does somewhat monitor their own forums. You can post there and generally, a Gengineer responds or someone who has been through the same thing.

Comment: Have the mx records been amended since switching away from Google apps?

Answer (score 1):

The error itself tends to indicate that Gmail is malforming the URL you are entering in that you are trying to enter the hostname of the smtp server and it is adding the domain name to the end. Try entering in just the host name of the SMTP server without the domain.com at the end and that may fix it.

I have not used Gmail with a private SMTP server in the past however it appears as though when you are setting up the SMTP server it may simply expect the host name of the SMTP server and not the fully qualified domain name.